# Why is there no Activity1 class in MonoGame Shared project for iOS and Android?

Tags: c#, monogame

I want to create a game for iOS and Android. Therefore, I created a MonoGame Shared project in Visual Studio Community for Mac. But in this project there is just the Game1 class, nothing more.

Normally, there is an Activity1 class in the project when I choose the MonoGame Android template instead of the MonoGame Shared project.
I need to edit the Acitivity1.cs for some specific Android code.

Why is there no Acitivity1.cs in the MonoGame Shared project?

Shared project(when I choose the MonoGame Shared project template):
[image]

Android project(when I choose the MonoGame Android template):
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it is a SHARED project.

Shared means all platform codes can use this project, but Activity is an Android specfied feature.

You may need to create 3 projects: Android, iOS and Shared. Wrtite the game logic codes in the shared project, and add this project as a reference of Android and iOS project.

Comment: First, I created an iOS project. After that, I added an Android project and a Shared project in the solution explorer. Finally, I added the references to the Shared project. Is it correct like this?

Comment: Add reference (the shared project) to Android and iOS projects. the shared project works as a library.

Comment: Ok, then I was wrong. Because I added a reference from the iOS project to the shared project and a reference from the Android project to the shared project. I removed both references. But how can I add a reference from the shared project to the iOS and the Android project? There is no references folder in the shared project.

Comment: Maybe right click the project and there is an add reference menu or add.. -> reference? Sorry I'm not familiar with mac.

Comment: I did the references as I mentioned before. They do it the same here: http://rion.io/2017/03/22/sharing-is-caring-using-shared-projects-in-asp-net/